# How to force a "pedantic" like errors about always setting types?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I come from object oriented languages such as Java and I'm trying to convert a .jsx module to a .tsx to make use of types.

I have to say it is pretty easy and straightforward but I don't like the following:

```
let methodName = 'GET';
```

This is a variable declaration in a method of mine. 
The compiler is fine with me not assigning a type, but coming from java I don't like that! I'd like to get an error "type of variable methodName is undefined" so that I'm forced to write it in this way:

```
let methodName:string = 'GET';
```

The same goes for my methods, for typescript the following is absolutely fine:

```
handleButtonClick = evt => {

}
```

but it's not fine at all, I should be forced to do something like this:

```
handleButtonClick = (evt:React.MouseEvent):void => {

}
```

Is it possible to achieve this by setting some option?

Comment: The compiler has a strict mode that turns on settings like noImplicitAny if that's what you mean. See https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html

Comment: Note that in many ways TS is much stricter than Java. If you declare it `const`, the type isn't even `string`, but `"GET"`. String literal types don't even exist in Java.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the [compiler options](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html) section of the documentation, you'll find the `--noImplicitAny` option that tells TypeScript not to allow implicit `any`.

Note, though, that your first example doesn't make `mehodName` implicitly `any`:

```
let methodName = 'GET';
```

TypeScript *infers* the type of `methodName` from what you're assigning it, and trying to assign something other than a string will be an error. The [type inference](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-inference.html) documentation goes into this in detail. A lot of the time, you don't need to explicitly type things, because the type can be inferred. The code is still typesafe.

This would implicitly make `methodName` of type `any`:

```
export let methodName;
```

With `--noImplicitAny`, that's an error. Without it, the implicit type `any` is used for the exported variable.